# IEEEtran not working

Tags: ieeetran

I am trying to use the IEEEtran for my document. I have used it in the past, but now I have a new system and have to install all the programs again. I downloaded IEEEtran.zip from a recommended source, and I copied the contents into /MikTek/tex/IEEEtran. But on using `{IEEEtran}` next to `\documentclass`, the system reports errors such as :

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "paper"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\1\Desktop\Paper and Thesis\Paper

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: paper.aux

======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTek"
package repository: http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: bcd18fcf486ebfeac5892e057437cdbc
going to download 2656528 bytes
going to install 14 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ieeetran.tar.lzma...
2656528 bytes, 496.61 KB/Sec
extracting files from ieeetran.tar.lzma...
bibtex.exe: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

bibtex.exe: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTek\bibtex/bib/ieeetran
======================================================================
I couldn't open style file IEEEtran.bst
---line 156 of file paper.aux
 : \bibstyle{IEEEtran
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file paper.aux
(There were 2 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf "C:\Users\1\Desktop\Paper and Thesis\Paper\paper.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\1\Desktop\Paper and Thesis\Paper

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/1/Desktop/Paper and Thesis/Paper/paper.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.

======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTek"
package repository: http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: bcd18fcf486ebfeac5892e057437cdbc
going to download 2656528 bytes
going to install 14 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/ieeetran.tar.lzma...
2656528 bytes, 415.28 KB/Sec
extracting files from ieeetran.tar.lzma...
pdflatex.exe: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

pdflatex.exe: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTek\bibtex/bib/ieeetran
======================================================================

! LaTeX Error: File `IEEEtran.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 

Process has been terminated ...
```

If I write something like :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{times,epsfig,latexsym,fancybox,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,cite,epsfig,amssymb,amsmath,endnotes,algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{srcltx}


\begin{document}
Hello, a test!
\end{document}
```

I should get a pdf file. For non-IEEEtran usage documents, it works fine

Comment: Something is going wrong during the automatic package installation process of MiKTeX. Try to install the class first by the [MiKTeX Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pkgmgt.html) and then try to compile anew. Some things in the error report like the execution of BibTeX are quite confusing though.

Comment: You should not modify the MikTeX folder by yourself. Remove your modifications and install the package either via `settings (admin)` or on-the-fly. You don't need to call the packages more than once (`amsmath` is called 3 times).